# Excel VBA: Find cells with similar values in a column

Tags: vba

I have in column A multiple strings of numbers that look like:

2222222266622222266666222222222222266622666666222
2222266666622222222666662222666222222666222222222
2222266622226666662266622266622222222222222222666
2222222222222666222226662266622226666622222222666
2666662266622222222222222222222666222222666222666
2222266622222666666666662266622222222222222222222
6662266622226662222266622222666222222266622222222
2666622666666222666222222666222222222222222222222
2222266626662666222222266622222222222666222266622
and so on.

I'm trying to find the values that are 90% the same or another percentage that I would choose before I run the program.

The expected result should be in column B how many other cells would share the same structure as much as an percentage with column A, and if it is possible in next column or columns, the cells that gave that similitude

My first try:

```
Sub Similar()
Dim stNow As Date
Dim DATAsheet As Worksheet
Dim firstrow As Integer
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim String_i, Len_i, String_j, Len_j
stNow = Now
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Set DATAsheet = Sheet1
DATAsheet.Select
firstrow = Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown).Row
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = firstrow To finalrow
  For j = firstrow To finalrow
    If i > 3 And j > 3 And i <> j Then
      String_i = Cells(i, 1).Value
      Len_i = Len(String_i)
      String_j = Cells(j, 1).Value
      Len_j = Len(String_j)
        For k = 1 To Len_i
         For l = 1 To Len_j
          If Mid(String_i, k, 1) = Mid(String_j, l, 1) Then
           Cells(j, 2).Value = Cells(j, 2).Value + 1
          End If
         Next l
        Next k
     End If
       DoEvents
   Next j
   Application.StatusBar = "Loop 1/1 --- Done:   " & Round((i / finalrow * 100), 0) & " %"
Next i
Application.StatusBar = ""
MsgBox "Done"
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

But it gaves me in column B the results:

259461.00
262794.00
262794.00
262794.00
259461.00
266123.00
259461.00
259461.00

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Comment: The values in column B are the total number of character matches between a string in column A and **all the other** strings in column A. So if the string in A4 had 3 matches with A5, 7 matches with A6, and 11 matches with A7, the value in B4 would be 21. This is almost certainly not the behaviour you want

Comment: Now that you point it out I see. I should mention that the expected result should be in column B how many other cells would share the same structure as much as an percentage with column A, and if it is possible in next column or columns, the cells that gave that similitude.

Answer (score 0):

VladMale first we will need lengt of this string - function LEN, and then we will need comparing substrings  - function MID. Second function should be made in some loop from first to last character in a string, and every time it will match, some other cell should count how many times it mached and how many not. The posivite result we can divide by the string length * 100 and compare if it is more or less than 90%

Comment: First we need to know how to write and run VBA macros - there is a special place to write it and syntax is different than writing = formula in cells. First find out on the web where is the place for VBA code, then try to learn some basics like this: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html   To finish this task will be needed knowledge about loops in VBA first. Dim means a variable, i is the name of variable,  As Integer means that this variable is the type Integer - also find out in the web what are other possible datatypes in VBA

Comment: You can also open the VBA editor with the keyboard shortcut Alt + F11. The most important property will be Cells.value - find this code: excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html use it in VBA editor and see what will happen

Comment: i <> j  in 21. row